# How clone observable with extenders in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

I found a lot of examples with cloning observable in Knockout, but all of these not support cloning extenders from one observable to another.
May be some one knows how clone extender too, when clones observable?

Comment: The `.extend` method is chainable, so target observables can be totally lost in extensions' closures. This extending approach makes cloning extended observables impossible in most cases. But I might be wrong with these conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched this case and found that it is not possible define extender as object, also not possible clone observable with extenders.